# Deleting multiple rows from a table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table and I want to delete all rows with a specific card serial . There are multiple rows with the same card serial .So I wrote this code but it seems that's not working:

```
try
{
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WF_AbsPres.Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString))
{
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("DELETE  FORM DevInOut where Cardserial='" + textBox5.Text + "'", con);
   command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
}
   catch (SqlException ex)
{
}
```

how can assure all the rows will be deleted . Should I use procedure? How do I use procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `FORM` to `FROM`.

And please always  use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* instead. This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WF_AbsPres.Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString))
{
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM DevInOut where Cardserial=@Cardserial", con);
   commdand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cardserial", textBox5.Text);
   command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

Read more from [`DELETE (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

Comment: Oh my God. What a silly mistake. And thanks for the tip on parameterized query.